# Ruby on rails, delayed job :run_at variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, delayed-job

I am running a job which send data to a rest api.

After the completion of all those requests, I need a 10 minute delay then a method will be called which will process on those sent requests.

```
def self.batch_task(batch_params)
    # a very long code
    Batch.delay.check_requests
end
```

My second method is check_requests

```
def self.check_requests
   puts 'hello darkness'
end

def check_requests
   self.check_requests
end
```

at the end, i am calling handle_asynchronously

```
handle_asynchronously :batch_task
handle_asynchronously :check_requests, :run_at => Proc.new { 10.minutes.from_now }
```

Batch_task runs correctly followed by check_reqeusts, **but I am not getting any the 10-minute delay before the function check_requests**.
My rake job is working fine. I also see the hello_darkness output in the console of rake jobs.

Comment: are you trying to create a delay inside delayed method? what if you just do `Batch.delay.check_requests` directly?`

Comment: that's what I want, first the delayed job will finish then the check_request will be called with 10 mins delay.

Comment: ok, but does it produce a delay of 10 minutes when you run it outside delayed job method?

Comment: no it is not producing any delay rather it just prints hello_darkness as soon as batch_task completes

Comment: Try `Batch.delay(run_at: 10.minutes.from_now).check_requests` in the `self.batch_task(batch_params)` method instead of `Batch.delay.check_requests`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `delay` like below in the `batch_task` method

```
def self.batch_task(batch_params)
  # a very long code
  Batch.delay(run_at: 10.minutes.from_now).check_requests
end

handle_asynchronously :batch_task
handle_asynchronously :check_requests
```